# ReactJS: STOMP subscription to multiple topics

Tags: reactjs, activemq-classic, spring-websocket, stomp

My React code creates a WebSocket connection to our company's ActiveMQ 5.15.5 server, and then subscribes to the following two topics: `salary` and `decoding`. The problem is that the code is only able to subscribe to one of the topics. It cannot subscribe to both.

```js
const client = window.Stomp.client(`ws://${ipAddress}:61614`, 'aj6.stomp');
const headers = { id: 'username' };
client.debug = null;
client.connect('user', 'pass', () => {
    client.subscribe(  
      '/topic/salary',  //BREAKPOINT was set here
      message => {
        const body = JSON.parse(message.body);
        if (body && body.pcId) {
          salaries[body.pcId] = body;
          setState({ salaries});
        }
      },
      headers,
    );
    client.subscribe(
      '/topic/decoding',  //BREAKPOINT was set here
      message => {
        const newBody = JSON.parse(message.body);
        if (newBody && newBody.PcID) {
          consoleMessage[newBody.PcID] = newBody;
          setState({ consoleMessage });
        }
      },
      headers,
    );
});
```

So in the code above I put a break-point at `client.subscribe('/topic/decoding...` and `client.subscribe('/topic/salary...`. I saw that it only subscribes to `/topic/decoding` but not `/topic/salary`.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue so that it subscribes to both topics?

Comment: Didn't you ask this same basic question recently? It appears to have been deleted now. Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I have, but I updated it once I had more information. Also if its very basic, do you think you can provide an answer then?

Comment: By "same basic question" I didn't mean that the question was basic, but that your new question was "basically the same" as the old question. I couldn't confirm that it was exactly the same since the old one had been deleted already. Also, if you have new information to add to a question then simply update the question rather than deleting it and creating a new one.

Comment: Fair enough i'll remember that for next time

Answer (score 0):

Try creating 2 clients, e.g.:

```js
const salaryClient = window.Stomp.client(`ws://${ipAddress}:61614`, 'aj6.stomp');
const salaryHeaders = { id: 'salary' };
salaryClient.debug = null;
salaryClient.connect('user', 'pass', () => {
    salaryClient.subscribe(  
      '/topic/salary',
      message => {
        const body = JSON.parse(message.body);
        if (body && body.pcId) {
          salaries[body.pcId] = body;
          setState({ salaries});
        }
      },
      salaryHeaders,
    );
});
const decodingClient = window.Stomp.client(`ws://${ipAddress}:61614`, 'aj7.stomp');
const decodingHeaders = { id: 'decoding' };
decodingClient.debug = null;
decodingClient.connect('user', 'pass', () => {
    decodingClient.subscribe(
      '/topic/decoding',
      message => {
        const newBody = JSON.parse(message.body);
        if (newBody && newBody.PcID) {
          consoleMessage[newBody.PcID] = newBody;
          setState({ consoleMessage });
        }
      },
      decodingHeaders,
    );
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not seem to work, I was still getting the same issue. Do I perhaps have to unsubscribe or disconnect before I connect/subscribe to the new client/topic respectively?

Comment: ActiveMQ can handle more than one connection and subscription. It would be kind of worthless otherwise. Therefore, I don't see why you would need to disconnect one client in order to connect another. The subscriptions are not even on the same topic. I've update my answer slightly. Could you try that?

Comment: Hey I tried your new solution and it looks like im still getting the same issue. For some reason the decoding code isnt being run at all and idk why

Comment: Try turning on STOMP protocol debug logging as described in the "Debugging" section [here](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html). Then run your client and add the log output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

[From Stomp documentation](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#SUBSCRIBE_id_Header):

> Since a single connection can have multiple open subscriptions with a server, an id header MUST be included in the frame to uniquely identify the subscription. The id header allows the client and server to relate subsequent MESSAGE or UNSUBSCRIBE frames to the original subscription.
> Within the same connection, different subscriptions MUST use different subscription identifiers.

Stomp API definition:

```
subscribe(destination, callback, headers = {})
```

So for my understanding, You can't have the same `username` id for both of your subscriptions

Comment: Is it possible to log out and then log back in with the same headers?